# How do I properly match Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a list of objects output from `ldapsearch` as follows:

```
dn: cn=HPOTTER,ou=STUDENTS,ou=HOGWARTS,o=SCHOOL
dn: cn=HGRANGER,ou=STUDENTS,ou=HOGWARTS,o=SCHOOL
dn: cn=RWEASLEY,ou=STUDENTS,ou=HOGWARTS,o=SCHOOL
dn: cn=DMALFOY,ou=STUDENTS,ou=HOGWARTS,o=SCHOOL
dn: cn=SSNAPE,ou=FACULTY,ou=HOGWARTS,o=SCHOOL
dn: cn=ADUMBLED,ou=FACULTY,ou=HOGWARTS,o=SCHOOL
```

---

So far, I have the following regex:

```
/\bcn=\w*,/g
```

Which returns results like this:

```
cn=HPOTTER,
cn=HGRANGER,
cn=RWEASLEY,
cn=DMALFOY,
cn=SSNAPE,
cn=ADUMBLED,
```

---

I need a regex that returns results like this:

```
HPOTTER
HGRANGER
RWEASLEY
DMALFOY
SSNAPE
ADUMBLED
```

What do I need to change in my regex so the pattern (the `cn=` and the comma) is not included in the results?

**EDIT:** I will be using `sed` to do the pattern matching, and piping the output to other command line utilities.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I would check out this excellent online regular expression tutorial:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/ .  It's how I learned.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use a regex here.  You have data in a simple comma separated format - make use of it!  use your favorite languages Split functionality to split on commas, and then split on ='s, and then you get your keys and values with no regex necessary.

Comment: @Robert P: I agree.  Regexes are awesome, but use a simpler tool if you can accomplish it.

Also, @eleven81, you might want to rename your question to something that indexes better for people with a similar question.  i.e. "How do I properly match Regular Expressions?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds more like a simple parsing problem and not regex.  An ANTLR grammar would sort this out in no time.

Comment: Wow.  A grammar is way overkill for this.

Answer (score 13):

You will have to perform a grouping.  This is done by modifying the regex to:

```
/\bcn=\(\w*\),/g
```

This will then populate your result into a grouping variable.  Depending on your language how to extract this value will differ.  (For you with *sed* the variable will be \1)

Note that most regex flavors you don't have to escape the brackets (), but since you're using *sed* you will need to as shown above.

For an excellent resource on Regular Expressions I suggest: [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570/)

Answer (score 4):

OK, the place where you asked the more specific question was closed as "exact duplicate" of this, so I'm copying my answer from there to here:

If you want to use sed, you can use something like the following:

`sed -e 's/dn: cn=\([^,]*\),.*$/\1/'`

You have to use `[^,]*` because in sed, `.*` is "greedy" meaning it will match everything it can before looking at any following character. That means if you use `\(.*\),` in your pattern it will match up to the last comma, not up to the first comma.

Comment: Put your sed command in `backquotes` so that it doesn't change your asterisks into Markdown formatting. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I learned about that shortly after posting this answer, but never came back to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) I have used it in the past to build my RegEx. It is good to help learning too.

Comment: +1, great free tool, helps immensely with debugging these rat's nests called regexs.

Comment: Or perhaps because it is not a direct answer to the question. Although it is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty method is to use submatches assuming your engine supports it:

```
/\bcn=(\w*),/g
```

Then you would want to get the first submatch.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what language you're using, we can't tell for sure, but in most regular expression parsers, if you use parenthesis, such as

/\bcn=(\w*),/g

then you'll be able to get the first matching pattern (often \1) as exactly what you are searching for.  To be more specific, we need to know what language you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If your regex supports Lookaheads and Lookbehinds then you can use

```
/(?<=\bcn=)\w*(?=,)/g
```

That will match

```
HPOTTER
HGRANGER
RWEASLEY
DMALFOY
SSNAPE
ADUMBLED
```

But not the `cn=` or the `,` on either side. The comma and `cn=` still have to be there for the match, it just isn't included in the result.

Comment: sed does support look behinds, however you'll need to use the Perl-mode switch (-R)